# Start geom_bar at y>0 / Deactivate clip on only one side

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running into problems with these 2 requirements:

- y-axis must start at 3
- some `geom_text` will range out of chart on the right

[image]

My ideas so far and their flaws:

- subtract -3 from all datasets and fake y-axis labels (would prefer not to)
- build a dummy `geom_bar` of height 3 (how to keep it out of legend?)

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

df=data.frame(
  Date=c("2012-11-30", "2012-12-03", "2012-12-04"),
  d1=c(12, 8, 13),
  d2=c(13, 7, 12),
  e1=c(7, 9, 8)
)

frame()
p=ggplot(df, aes(Date)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y=e1, fill="e1"), stat="identity", color="red") +
    geom_line(aes(y=d1, group=1, color="d1")) +
    geom_line(aes(y=d2, group=1, color="d2")) +
    geom_text(aes(x =3.5, y=c(14,13,12), label=c("Text1","Text2","Text3"))) +
    scale_colour_manual(" ", values=c("e1"="red", "d1"="blue", "d2"="black"))+
    scale_fill_manual("", values="red") +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(3,15), xlim=c(0.5,3.5)) +
    theme(legend.key=element_blank(),legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.position="top", legend.box="horizontal",
          plot.margin=unit(c(1, 2, 1, 1), "cm"))

p1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
p1$layout$clip[p1$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(p1)
```

Comment: What about using `grid.text` for the annotations

Comment: mnel: Thanks. `grid.text` annotations cannot be positioned relative to `ggplot2`-coordinates (i.e. at `x=3.5`), can they?

Comment: Exact positioning is important for some of the annotations, so I'd prefer to keep them in ggplot2 if at all possible

Comment: @Frank does your geom_texts are a plot legend? I mean like a second legend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you define your own scale transformation

```
library(scales)
translate3_trans <- function() {
  trans <- function(x) x - 3
  inv   <- function(x) x + 3
  trans_new("translate3_trans", trans, inv)
}
```

then you add

```
       p <- p + scale_y_continuous(trans="translate3")
```

[image]

I don't understand where do you want to put the geom_text exactly.

PS : Sorry , I change the alpha to 0.5 because your red hurts my eyes.